# How to make text baseline and midline visible in Word?

Tags: microsoft-word, vba, microsoft-word-2007

I want to make baseline and midline (or x-height line to be precise) visible (and printable) in a line of text (presuming characters in the line are the same font and size). Is it possible to do so more or less automatically in Microsoft Word (save for manually adding and aligning line objects with each text line, which is not going to be very accurate anyway)?
(I'm using Word 2007 on Windows 7, but actually would consider any other options if they are free.)
[image: Picture worth a thousand words]

Comment: You might need to use something like .Information(wdVerticalPositionRelativeToPage) and work with the actual position on screen

Comment: Yeah if 72 points is an inch and you know the size of your text relative to that, something like `ActiveDocument.Shapes.AddLine(xpos, ypos + 10, xpos + Len(w), ypos + 10).Select` or whatever might work. I can get it kind of working, but not fine tuned. You have to be in print layout - zoom 1 page for it to be accurate

Comment: Honestly if you try it that way and need to fine tune it, this is one of those times where I think SO might have a better audience to answer it. Good luck!